# ConditionalPanel with sliderInput based on swithcInput

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a prediction tool and based on some characteristics, I will compute a risk prediction.

Since it will be a worldwide tool, I would like to have the option for people to fill in their weight either in KG or LB.

I tried to make a switchInput switching between KG and LB and based on this switch, I would like either a sliderInput to show up for KG or for LB (so not both at the same time). (KG will be default)

I tried to use ConditionalPanel, but it does not work.

Can anyone suggest something that may work?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title=div( "Risk prediction tool")),

  p("Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (COPD) is a lung problem that can affect people mainly as they get older."),

  selectInput("sex", label=p("What is your gender?"),
              choices=list("Female"=1, "Male"=0), selected=1), 

  sliderInput("age", label=p("What is your age?"), min = 18, max = 90, value = 35),

  strong("What is your weight?"),
  br(),
  switchInput("switchweight", value = TRUE , onLabel = "kg", offLabel = "lb"),

  conditionalPanel(condition = "switchweight == TRUE",
                   sliderInput("weightKG", label=NULL, min = 25, max = 200, value = 75)),
  conditionalPanel(condition = "switchweight == FALSE",
                   sliderInput("weightLB", label=NULL, min = 55, max = 440, value = 165))
)


# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `TRUE` and `FALSE` are R variables; in Javascript this is `true` and `false`. Moreover it should be `condition = "input.switchweight == ...`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!