# Using switchInput in server

Tags: r, shiny

Related to question [ConditionalPanel with sliderInput based on swithcInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54466325/conditionalpanel-with-sliderinput-based-on-swithcinput):

I am working on a prediction tool and based on some characteristics, I will compute a risk prediction.

Since it will be a worldwide tool, I would like to have the option for people to fill in their weight either in KG or LB.

I made a switchInput switching between KG and LB and based on this switch, people can either put their weight in KG or for LB (so not both at the same time). (KG will be default)

How can I in the server convert weight in LB to KG if switch is on LB and use input from input$weightKG if switch is on KG?

The following does not work:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
        
LBtoKG <- function(weightLB) { 
    round(0.45359237*weightLB,0)
}
    
# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title = div("Risk prediction tool")),
  p("Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (COPD) is a lung problem that can affect people mainly as they get older."),
        
  selectInput("sex", label = p("What is your gender?"),
              choices = list("Female" = 1, "Male" = 0), selected = 1), 
        
  sliderInput("age", label = p("What is your age?"), min = 18, max = 90, value = 35),
  
  strong("What is your weight?"),
  br(),
  switchInput("switchweight", value = TRUE , onLabel = "kg", offLabel = "lb"),
  
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.switchweight == true",
    sliderInput("weightKG", label = NULL, min = 25, max = 200, value = 75, round=0)
  ),
  
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.switchweight == false",
    sliderInput("weightLB", label = NULL, min = 55, max = 440, value = 165, round = 0)
  )
)
        
# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  weight <- eventReactive(input$switchweight, {
    switch(input$switchweight,
           "true" = as.numeric(as.character(input$weightKG)),
           "false" = LBtoKG(as.numeric(as.character(input$weightLB)))
    )
  })
}
        
# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What does not work exactly ? Don't you have the expected value in `weight()` ?

Comment: Only the initial state displays correct values.

Comment: Just some more feedback since you mentioned you are new to shiny below your answer. In my eyes the problem with this question wasn’t shiny related, it is a conflict of conduct.
You asked a question which I answered properly.
After you got my answer you embedded my code in your question and added further restrictions about how the answer should look like.
Then you are telling me my answer doesn’t cover those restrictions and two minutes after I edited my answer accordingly to the new information you come up with your “own” answer which is mainly based on mine. That’s an insulting approach.

Comment: More info about this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253762/link-for-poor-or-ever-growing-questions-to-better-explain-why-people-stop-answer

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd go with `updateSliderInput` instead of `conditionalPanel`s:
Edit: Introduced weightKG which is independent of the user selection.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title=div( "Risk prediction tool")),

  p("Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (COPD) is a lung problem that can affect people mainly as they get older."),

  selectInput("sex", label=p("What is your gender?"),
              choices=list("Female"=1, "Male"=0), selected=1), 

  sliderInput("age", label=p("What is your age?"), min = 18, max = 90, value = 35),

  strong("What is your weight?"),
  br(),
  switchInput("switchweight", value = TRUE , onLabel = "kg", offLabel = "lb"),

  sliderInput("weight", label=NULL, min = 25, max = 200, value = 75, round=0)
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  weightKG <- reactiveVal(isolate(input$weight))

  observeEvent(input$weight, {
    if(input$switchweight){
      weightKG(round(input$weight, digits = 0))
    } else {
      weightKG(round(input$weight/2.2046226, digits = 0))
    }
    print(weightKG())
  })

  observeEvent(input$switchweight, {
    if(input$switchweight){
      updateSliderInput(session, "weight", label=NULL, min = 25, max = 200, value = isolate({input$weight/2.2046226}))
    } else {
      updateSliderInput(session, "weight", label=NULL, min = 55, max = 440, value = isolate({input$weight*2.2046226}))
    }
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Yes this works, but I need to always use as input in my risk prediction weight in KG and never in LB. so when slider is put on LB, I need to convert it to KG and put it in my risk prediction (see example above (is not real model)).

Comment: Please see my edit. Btw. you shouldn't update your question with an answers code. This leads to confusion for all others that are trying to retrace this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem with your `switch` statement. Try:

```
switch(as.character(input$switchweight),
          "TRUE" = as.numeric(as.character(input$weightKG)),
           "FALSE" = LBtoKG(as.numeric(as.character(input$weightLB))))
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally found how it would work!

A combination of your answers pointed me in the right direction.

Here is a working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title=div( "Risk prediction tool")),

  p("Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (COPD) is a lung problem that can affect people mainly as they get older."),

  selectInput("sex", label=p("What is your gender?"),
              choices=list("Female"=1, "Male"=0), selected=1), 

  sliderInput("age", label=p("What is your age?"), min = 18, max = 90, value = 35),

  strong("What is your weight?"),
  br(),
  switchInput("switchweight", value = TRUE , onLabel = "kg", offLabel = "lb"),
    sliderInput("weight", label=NULL, min = 25, max = 200, value = 75, round=0),

  actionButton("submit", label = "Generate Prediction"),

  p('Your predicted risk (%) of developing COPD in your lifetime is:'),
  verbatimTextOutput("prediction")

)


# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {

   copdRisk <- function(age, sex, weight) {
    (exp(-5.00   +(-0.004*(as.numeric(as.character(age)))) 
         +(0.40*(as.numeric(as.character(sex))))
         +(0.10*(as.numeric(as.character(weight)))) # in cm!
    ))}


  observeEvent(input$switchweight, {
    if(input$switchweight){
      updateSliderInput(session, "weight", label=NULL, min = 25, max = 200, value = isolate({input$weight/2.2046226}))
    } else {
      updateSliderInput(session, "weight", label=NULL, min = 55, max = 440, value = isolate({input$weight*2.2046226}))
    }
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)


  prediction <- observe({ 

    ## some coding that will convert LB weight in to KG when switch is on LB
    weight <- 
      if(as.character(input$switchweight) == TRUE) {input$weight
      } else {round(input$weight/2.2046226)}


    risks <- (copdRisk(age = input$age, sex=input$sex, weight=weight #WHICH needs to always in CM!
                       ))

    output$prediction <- renderText({
      round(risks, 1)})
  }) 
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: In your initial question you didn't point out that weight needs to be constantly in KG for the prediction model - accordingly I consider posting your "own" answer bad style.

Comment: And this: `if(as.character(input$switchweight) == TRUE){...}` is not a combination of answers, this is just one of the worst if-clauses I've ever seen. Your switchInput returns a boolean already.

Comment: Fine, I am just happy that it works now. (I am very new to working with shiny)

Comment: Well, just have a look at this code snippet once again: input$switchweight gives a logical value about whether the user selected Kg or lb. You are converting this logical value to a string and then you are checking if it equals the the logical constant "TRUE". `if(input$switchweight)` gives you the same behaviour without all the converting nonsense (And this is exactly what I have used in my answer.. therefore its not a combination). Stéphane Laurent used the conversion to pass it to the `switch()` function which expects an expression evaluating to a number or a character string.